# Silverstripe - assign Template to Controller manually

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

at the moment I´m working with a custom Silverstripe Controller with a Director rule:

```
---
Name: myroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'category/$Action/$Slug': 'Category_Controller'
```

The Controller looks like that:

```
class Category_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    public function show($arguments) {
       echo "Slug: " . $arguments->param("Slug");
   }
}
```

When I open in the browser the URL http://mysite.com/category/show/mobile
then the output look fine like this: "Slug: mobile".

I just wonder how I can use a Category.ss Template from the Folder "themes/templates/Layout" to render the Output. Then of course the container html (with header/footer) from Page.ss should be included as well. Just as usual when you have a custom Page Controller/Class and a corresponding Template in the Layout Folder.

I just tried this:

```
public function show($arguments) {
    echo $this->renderWith("Category");
}
```

It uses Category.ss for rendering the output, but there is no container html...

Thx for any help.
Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also pass an array to `renderWith()`, and it will try through the array until it finds a template.

so lets say `$this->renderWith(array('Category', 'Page'));`
it will first look for a template called  `Category.ss`, but will not find it (in the templates folder, not layout folder), it will then find `Page.ss` and use it.
Now it hits `$Layout` inside `Page.ss` and it checks the array again inside the Layout folder, it will now find the `Category.ss`, which is exactly what you where looking for if I got the question right.

if you do not want to do `return $this->renderWith();` you can also just do `return $this;` and silverstripe will get the action you called and the class hierarchy of $this and use that as array for `renderWith()`

So if your classes are `Category_Controller > Page_Controller > ContentController` the array will look like this:

```
array(
    'Category_show', // because your action is show
    'Category',
    'Page_show',
    'Page',
    'ContentController_show',
    'ContentController',
)
```

(I am not a 100% sure if it also includes Page_show and ContentController_show.)

Comment: i also found this code working: 
$ssv=new SSViewer("Page"); 
$ssv->setTemplateFile("Layout", "Category"); 
echo $this->renderWith($ssv);